# EXT4-fs error (device loop0): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced:

Tags: linux, filesystems, hard-drive, ext4

```
EXT4-fs error (device loop0): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced:
```

Is this a serious issue? Just noticed it after doing a 15GB CPanel Account Restore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a sign of a dirty filesystem which should be fixable by running an `fsck` on the filesystem.

Comment: This requires the data center to unmount the drive and fsck it right?

If I don't this could get worse right?

Would there be risk of data loss?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to unmount the filesystem before running fsck.  You didn't specify how many inodes it was complaining about but it is advisable to run it to clean up orphaned references.